# Inverse Function + Reflection In Y-Axis

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, graphing-functions, transformation

Not getting any of the answers in MC.

Is the answer wrong, or have I done something wrong?

[image]

Comment: What is MC? Try looking at the point $(0,f(0))$ and see where that would be under the specified transformation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f^{-1}$ is the symmetric of f respect to $y=x$.

$x\mapsto f^{-1}(-x)$ is the symmetric of $f^{-1}$  respect to the vertical axis.

Apply sequentially both symmetries to the graph of $f$.

Comment: yup did that and my graph looks like neither..

Comment: In what *order* do yo apply the symmetries?

Comment: oh yup i did it again... silly error. got it, thanks!